# Identity Server 4 and Sitecore Federated Authentication Error

Tags: federated-authentication

I've been working on an integration of logging in users in Sitecore via Federated Authentication with Identity Server 4 based on Open ID.  Unfortunately I've followed every recommendation I could follow so far, but I'm getting a strange error:

> 16592 12:08:38 WARN  Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware - The state field is missing or invalid.

I've research Open Id using this as a reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code and discovered the state is a field that is typically uniquely generated.  I assume this should have on the sign in request that Sitecore makes to the Authority for a Sign-In request.  My assumption is that Sitecore generates this request behind the scenes, but any idea why the State is not being generated?

A little sampling of my current configuration:

```
    <pipelines>
        <owin.identityProviders>
            <processor type="Site.Foundation.Identity.Processor.SitecoreIdentityServerProvider, Site.Foundation" resolve="true" />
        </owin.identityProviders>
    </pipelines>

    <federatedAuthentication>
        <identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites">
            <!--The list of providers assigned to all sites-->
            <mapEntry name="all websites" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                <sites hint="list">
                    <site>website</site>
                </sites>
                <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
                    <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='SitecoreIdentityServer']" />
                </identityProviders>
                <externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                    <param desc="isPersistentUser">false</param>
                </externalUserBuilder>
            </mapEntry>

        </identityProvidersPerSites>
        <identityProviders>
            <identityProvider id="SitecoreIdentityServer" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
                <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
                <caption>Log in with Identity Server</caption>
                <icon>/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/Images/24x24/bas.png</icon>
                <domain>sitecore</domain>
                <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
                    <!--SetIdpClaim transformation-->
                    <transformation name="set idp claim" ref="federatedAuthentication/sharedTransformations/setIdpClaim" />
                </transformations>
            </identityProvider>
        </identityProviders>
        <propertyInitializer type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.PropertyInitializer, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
            <maps hint="list">
                <map name="email claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                    <data hint="raw:AddData">
                        <source name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" />
                        <target name="Email" />
                    </data>
                </map>
                <map name="email verified" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                    <data hint="raw:AddData">
                        <source name="email_verified" />
                        <target name="EmailVerified" />
                    </data>
                </map>
                <map name="first name" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                    <data hint="raw:AddData">
                        <source name="given_name" />
                        <target name="FirstName" />
                    </data>
                </map>
                <map name="middle name" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                    <data hint="raw:AddData">
                        <source name="middle_name" />
                        <target name="MiddleName" />
                    </data>
                </map>
                <map name="last name" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                    <data hint="raw:AddData">
                        <source name="family_name" />
                        <target name="LastName" />
                    </data>
                </map>
            </maps>
        </propertyInitializer>
    </federatedAuthentication>

    <settings>
        <setting name="FederatedAuthentication.Enabled">
            <patch:attribute name="value">true</patch:attribute>
        </setting>
        <setting name="IdentityServer.ClientId" value="identityservertestclient" />
        <setting name="IdentityServer.ClientSecret" value="client-secret-removed-for-security" />
        <!-- connect/authorize -->
        <setting name="IdentityServer.Authority" value="Url-To-The-Identity-Server-Path" />
        <setting name="IdentityServer.MetadataAddress" value="Url-To-The-Identity-Server-OpenId-Configuration" />
    </settings>

    <services>
        <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseAuthenticationManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
                  implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Security.AuthenticationManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
                  lifetime="Singleton" />
        <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseTicketManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
                  implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Security.TicketManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
                  lifetime="Singleton" />
        <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BasePreviewManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
                  implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Publishing.PreviewManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
                  lifetime="Singleton" />
    </services>
</sitecore>
```

And the Middleware script:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;
using Sitecore.Configuration;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration;
using Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.IdentityProviders;
using Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Site.Foundation.Identity.Processor
{
    public class SitecoreIdentityServerProvider : IdentityProvidersProcessor
    {
        private readonly FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration _federatedAuthenticationConfiguration;
        public SitecoreIdentityServerProvider(FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration federatedAuthenticationConfiguration) : base(federatedAuthenticationConfiguration)
        {
            _federatedAuthenticationConfiguration = federatedAuthenticationConfiguration;
        }

        protected override string IdentityProviderName => "SitecoreIdentityServer";

        protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
            IdentityProvider provider = this.GetIdentityProvider();
            string authenticationType = this.GetAuthenticationType();

            args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = Settings.GetSetting("IdentityServer.ClientId"),
                Caption = provider.Caption,
                AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                AuthenticationType = authenticationType,
                //SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                Scope = "openid",
                UseTokenLifetime = false,

                Authority = Settings.GetSetting("IdentityServer.Authority"),
                MetadataAddress = Settings.GetSetting("IdentityServer.MetadataAddress"),
                ResponseType = "code id_token",

                ClientSecret = Settings.GetSetting("IdentityServer.ClientSecret"),

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = (context) => SecurityTokenValidation(context, provider)
                }
            });
        }

        private Task SecurityTokenValidation(SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context, IdentityProvider provider)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity identity = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

            foreach (var claimTransformationService in provider.Transformations)
            {
                claimTransformationService.Transform(identity, new TransformationContext(_federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, provider));
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shot in the dark, but are you on 9? http://blog.baslijten.com/enable-federated-authentication-and-configure-auth0-as-an-identity-provider-in-sitecore-9-0/

Comment: Yup on 9, turns out I solved this issue.  It's caused by an issue with the configuration above.  At some point I will answer with what I needed to change...

Comment: Hey @DylanYoung, interested in knowing what the solution was.

Comment: @DylanYoung could you please post the solution?